# Error in writing output from python to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am supposed to generate a csv file with 10 columns (from A to J) with 10000 rows that contain random numbers between 1 to 1000. I am able to get the desired output but cannot write this output to a csv file. Please find my code and the generated error message below.

```
import random
import csv

with open('table.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_write = csv.writer(file,delimiter="\t")

    for i in range(ord('A'), ord('J')+1):
        csv_write.writerow(chr(i), end="\t")

    for j in range(1,11):
        for k in range(1,1001):
            csv_write.writerow(random.randint(1,10001), end="\t")
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rida_\Desktop\tables.py", line 8, in <module>
    csv_write.writerow(chr(i), end="\t")
TypeError: writerow() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Did you think [`writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) should take keywords for some reason? You indentation is off by the way, please fix it so that it is more readable for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like writenow only takes the string as an arg, nothing else.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow

If you want a `\t` at the end just do `chr(i)+'\t'`. Char just converts a single character though. I think you're looking for `str(i)+'\t'`

So,

`csv_write.writerow(str(i)+'\t')`

And

`csv_write.writerow(str(random.randint(1,10001))+'\t'`

When you specified delimiter `\t` when creating the csv_write I think it will end the row with `\t` anyway so you don't need to append it to the end. Might have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) when you open a CSV file for write, you will give a `delimiter` and `quotechar` and other staff, so here in your case you dont need to pass `end="\t"` to `writerow`. this method just gives a list to write in your file. good luck.